# Check if the IdExample and DateExample is already exists and show a error?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an IdExample and a DateExample, and I want to check if they already exists in the db, using only code behind (c#).

Here is an exemple :

I have Idexample = 1  and DateExample = 20/05/2019.
If i insert it in database, I don't want to be able to insert it again, because it already exists in database.

```
DateTime exampleDate1= new DateTime();
DateTime exampleDate2= new DateTime();
            exampleDate1= Convert.ToDateTime(DateExample.Text);
            exampleDate2= Convert.ToDateTime(DateExample.Text);
if(exampleDate1.CompareTo(exampleDate2) == 0)
{
    /// Message
}

I want to check even the Idexample with the date because i want to check them in the same time if they exists already 
if
(Idexample = Id and DateExample = dd/mm/yyy)

{
  //// message they already exists
}
```

Comment: Use a `SELECT` statement and if you get any rows, then the answer is "yes"? But, if you want to stop multiple entries for a specific ID and date, then why not use a Unique constraint in the data engine instead? It'll be far better at doing this task than having your application trying to check.

Comment: i need this thing to work by using just codice not sql

Comment: You'll have to use some SQL, how else do you propose you find out what data in in a table without using it? If you *have* to use c# to decide, then use a parametrised SQL Statement to get a count, or return a dataset. and if you get a count, or a result with more rows than 0 then you know you'll about to try to process a duplicate.

Comment: using class or something like that, or using other thing that in hand just need a breve thing to begin with it.

Comment: @BlackHoleVideos effectively you're asking for a data access tutorial. The code has nothing to do with the question itself. That's too broad for SO and needs an entire article just to describe ADO.NET, ORMs, EF, Dapper etc. All tutorials, coursed, books on .NET cover this. Check the `Getting Started` tutorials for whatever stack you target. All of them show how to read from a database

Comment: For example, [ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/) is the underlying technology for all data access libraries. The [Working with SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) page in the ASP.NET Core tutorial shows how to read data from the database using EF Core. Entity Framework has [an entire site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/) that explains how each version works.